# Select dropdown inline label text

Tags: html, css, html-select

I want to insert a label inside my select dropdown.

[image]

Here, ***Sell in*** is the label text and ***United States*** is one of the dropdown options.
What's the best way to implement this.I feel i'll have to write a custom dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/rw6d2r25/6/

```css
select {
    padding-left:65px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #333;
    width:300px;
    display:block;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
label {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    pointer-events:none;
    text-indent:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
label, select {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<label>Sell In:</label>
<select>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United AE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `<select>` naked:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 10pt;}
select {border: none; color: #666;}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Sell in</span>
  <select>
    <option>United States</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: It's a hack but is not the correct behaviour I think

Comment: The user need a solution like I write in my answer, but bad-readers-speed-finger-downvote people is making good his job... no read.

Comment: ok , if the user need only it he must to tell us. But if he need to style entire select component he needs a plugin like chosen or select2. Thank to user that downvote me without reason and without read.

Comment: I agree with you @MarcosPérezGude!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. native `<select>` tag doesn't accept improvements or advanced styling. You can try with plugins like chosen or select2 from jquery plugin registry

- [Chosen](https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen)
- [Select2](https://plugins.jquery.com/select2)

Comment: Even I would downvote your answer as it is only a link based. Just give a few demo or some code.

Comment: Man... Something like how to use the plugin. `$("select").select2()` will also do!!! Grrr...

Comment: oK, it's true, but not a helpful code. Sorry for my english and for answer so tiny.

Comment: User doesn't tell us what solution he needs. I go out from this topic